# Options for migrating Windows 2012 R2 DC to Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, samba, dns

I have a small Windows domain, with the PDC running on Windows 2012 R2.  I am interested in retiring the Windows server and replacing it with a primary and backup DC's hosted on Linux VM's.

The configuration of the existing Windows domain is very simple.  I am primarily interested in the user directory for authentication of network shares and a centralized infrastructure for user accounts.  The existing PDC is also providing DHCP and DNS service to my network.

Off the top of my head, I am guessing that the simplest way to do this, and also to make future maintenance simple, is to set up two Linux VM's (likely running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), hosted on separate physical machines. Ideally, I would like to use a container solution, like Docker to make deployment of the DC's, and also disaster recovery, straightforward.

The end goal is to replace all of my Windows infrastructure machines with Linux machines.  The client machines will be a mix of Windows and Linux.  Oh, and I do have a Synology NAS, which is currently a domain member for file access control.  It will need to work with whatever I set up as a replacement to the Windows DC.

What I am finding, is that there is a bewildering mountain of discussion on various parts of this, with much of the content pretty outdated.  The other thing is that I am very familiar with Windows Server (almost 30 years as a software engineer writing low level network services on Windows), and I am familiar with running Linux as a desktop workstation, including as a Samba client.  I have no experience running the domain controller features in Samba, and I have no experience running any container solutions yet, either.

I would appreciate any pointers to relevant documentation that is concise and also relevant in 2023.  Also, since I mainly want single sign on user management, I would be open to pointers on alternate options that are not necessarily Windows Domain based.

Thanks for any suggestions or pointers!

Comment: Have you seen the official Ubuntu Server docs (https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ldap-introduction, https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/kerberos-introduction, etc.) Since this is a broad question, can you narrow it down to specific things you want to do - setting up DHCP, or setting up DNS, or ssetting up LDAP, and post specific questions for each separate thing?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I shouldn't have mentioned DHCP or DNS.  Those are both straightforward.  I don't need any help with that.  I only brought them up because the machine that I am retiring is also providing those services.

The breadth of the question is part of the problem.  I can find bits and pieces of the answers here and there.

What I am really looking for is a focused discussion on replacing a Windows PDC with a Linux equivalent.  What I want to do is to make this change with minimal impact to the clients.  And I can't have the clients out of service for a long period.

Comment: Oh, and I just took a look at the two links you provided.  Unless it's buried within some of the further links, there is no discussion of migrating a production domain from Windows, keeping the existing users.  I would really like to understand the end-to-end process, so that I know exactly what I am doing *before* I take my domain down, since things get time sensitive once users can't log in anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, I have done some further reading on Windows integration with LDAP, and I think that it's a dead end.

I need to be able to manage the user accounts that log into the Windows machines on my network, and it looks like Windows doesn't integrate with LDAP in that way.  Presumably, that also makes manually setting up Kerberos another dead end, since presumably in this context, Kerberos provides authentication services for LDAP.

The more that I read, the more that it seems that my best (only?) option is to consider running AD on Samba and then joining the Windows machines to that domain.

Comment: Making a seamless transition from Windows AD to Samba AD seems problematic, since I've read lots of reports that mixing the two server types in a single domain is fraught with peril.

Surely, there must be people out there who've done exactly what I am trying to do.  It seems like it would be a pretty common scenario...

Answer (score 1):

I have finished my research on this, and am in the process of updating my network infrastructure, and I wanted to circle back with my conclusion.

I was never able to find a solution to migrate from Windows Server to a Linux solution.

I have set up a Linux DNS and DHCP server (and will be adding a live backup in the near future).  For Active Directory, it looks like I will have to do the following:

1. For each Windows domain member machine, I will need to move the
   existing domain accounts to local accounts.  I'll be using Forensit
   User Profile Wizard to do this.
2. I will remove my NAS from the
   Windows domain (which will temporarily break access for domain
   authenticated users).
3. I will install Samba Active Directory and
   create a new domain with the same FQDN as my old Windows domain.
4. I'll create new AD users with the same names as the deleted Windows
   domain.
5. I'll join the NAS to the new domain and fix up authentication for the domain authenticated shares.
6. I'll join each Windows machine to the new Samba domain.
7. I'll move the local user accounts that I moved to local in step 1 to the Samba domain.

At that point, everything should be migrated to the Samba domain.  If there are any problems, I'd deal with them as they happen.

I was hoping for a more automated solution, but at this point, I doubt that it exists.

-Wade